# Website creates a new non-existent webpage after I visit website/class_id

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

My website creates a new non-existent website, after I visit my website/näytä_luokka/#  (also, class_id). If I try to go to a page that is in the same urls.py file, I get an error because it tries to find a page website/näytä_luokka/luokat instead of going to website/luokat. This happens through navbar. If I try to go to a link that is in another urls.py, everything works fine. Switching from /luokat to other pages works also fine.

I am using django to create website.

So, here's a couple examples from my

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

path('näytä_luokka/<luokka_id>', views.näytä_luokka, name="näytä-luokka"),

path('luokat', views.kaikki_luokat, name="luokat"),
]
```

**and .views**

```
def näytä_luokka(request, luokka_id):
    luokkalistaus = luokka.objects.get(pk=luokka_id)
    return render(request, 'tietokanta/näytä_luokat.html', 
        {'luokkalistaus': luokkalistaus})
```

```
def kaikki_luokat(request):
    luokkalista = luokka.objects.all().order_by('nimi')
    return render(request, 'tietokanta/luokat.html', 
        {'luokkalista': luokkalista})
```

**the navbar**

```
     
            </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="luokat">Luokat</a>
      </li>
```

I tried adding / after id number, but id didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in your urls.py
`path('näytä_luokka/<luokka_id>', views.näytä_luokka, name="näytä-luokka"),`

Specifically, the `<luokka_id>` is what is creating a webpage for you.  That is what is supposed to happen in a path like that.  It's the beauty of what Django can do; create urls dynamically, in this case a page that follows a template, but is unique to `luokka_id`.

The error you get when you try `website/näytä_luokka/luokat` happens because your view `def näytä_luokka(request, luokka_id):` is looking for what I guess is a number (an `int`) for the `luokka_id` but instead you are feeding it the string 'luokat' because that is the part of the url after `website/näytä_luokka/`.

Now, in your template you are referencing the `href` incorrectly.  It should be:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'luokat' %}">Luokat</a>
</li>
```

I would need to see more of your code, and maybe a better sense of what you want your page to do in order to help further, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes.

1. By default `<luokka_id>` url param is considered as `str` type i.e. `<str:luokka_id>` and `<luokka_id>` is same. So it should be `<int:luokka_id>`.

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('näytä_luokka/<int:luokka_id>/', views.näytä_luokka, name="näytä-luokka"),
    path('luokat/', views.kaikki_luokat, name="luokat"),
]
```

2. You should [`url tags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) correctly, so in template it should be:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'luokat' %}">Luokat</a>
</li>
```

> **Note:** Always give `/` at the end of every route.